# Saving web page periodically

Tags: browser-addons, archiving, web, autosave

Is there anyway of automatically save a web page periodically, e.g. everyday? What I want is something like https://archive.org/ but locally (and just for some sites).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway of automatically save a web page periodically, e.g. everyday?

Yes.

A basic method is to use e.g. a cross-platform scripting language (such as [Python](https://www.python.org/) or perhaps even [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.1)) for automation. Tools such as [wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), [curl](https://curl.se/), [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) or even a browser such as Chrome or Firefox (assuming the page uses Javascript to render parts of itself) are another option, possibly in combination with scripting (above). You can then set your system to save the data (i.e. run your program or script) on a regular basis (with e.g. `cron` for *Nix or Task Scheduler for Windows).

> What I want is something like https://archive.org/ but locally (and just for some sites).

You will likely need to build this yourself  (assuming you mean copying the actual web page functionality).

---

**Notes**

*Browser Automation*

- Modern versions of Chrome and Firefox can run without a graphical UI, colloquially known as "headless" mode.
- For automating Chrome or Firefox in "headless" mode, you may want to check out [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).
- If you are going to automate "Chrome", I would suggest looking at the [Ungoogled Chromium builds from Woolyss](https://chromium.woolyss.com/).

*JavaScript*

- Some JavaScript page portions may not be rendered correctly (i.e. at all) if A) a command line tool is used or B) a given browser is ran in "headless" mode. So this may not be a viable option for some pages (you'll have to have a browser/GUI visible).
- In rare cases, you may have to automate the browser GUI "Save As" functionality with something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to get all the JavaScript rendered data.
- You may have to script browser interactions (e.g. page scrolling) to get JavaScript rendered data to load in some cases.

---

*Moderately up-to-date Windows builds of `wget` are available [here](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/).*